# Define loop count in blogger xml

Tags: xml, label, blogger

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <data:label.name/>
    ,
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

This loop lists all the labels in a post,

is it possible to limit the number of labels shown by controlling the loop (defining a loop count)?

Eg: There are total 7 labels in a post but i want only the first 3 to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' index='x'>
    <b:if cond='data:x==0'><data:label.name/>, </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:x==1'><data:label.name/>, </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:x==2'><data:label.name/></b:if>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Or simply use `<` or `>` (encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively):

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' index='x'>
    <b:if cond='data:x&lt;=2'><data:label.name/>, </b:if>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to directly add the `limit` keyword followed by the number to the `values` field

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels limit 3' var='label'>
    <data:label.name/>
    ,
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible to create new variable data and assign value to it in Blogger template XML. There is no documentation from Google that give information about it. Blogger template XML is not designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

This one will show your first three labels (count starts from zero). 2 commas are also included, no comma for the third label.

```
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' index='x'>
  <b:if cond='data:x &#60;=2'>
    <a class='sfa-tag' expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'>
      <data:label.name/>
    </a>
    <b:if cond='data:x &#60;=1'>,</b:if>
  </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution :

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' index='sth'>
    <b:if cond='data:sth&lt;3'>
    <data:label.name/> ,
    </b:if>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

In blogger :
`<` = `&lt;` and `>` = `&gt;`

And I've used this statment : `sth&lt;3` Which means `sth<3`, so that the loop will repeat 3 times, hence, 3 entries should show up (Because the loop starts from 0)

You could also create a range **adding** new statment as shown below :

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' index='sth'>
    <b:if cond='data:sth&lt;6 and data:sth&gt;2'>
    <data:label.name/> ,
    </b:if>
  </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

The code above will show 3 labels picked up from the `3rd loop` to the `5th loop`.